# Xenforo In which table it save password

Tags: wordpress, xenforo

I used xenforo with wordpress. I need to know password field name.
I tried a lot to serach password field but failed to find.

In which table xenforo save password?

Answer (score 1):

The passwords are hashed using Secure Hash Algorithm 1 (SHA1) and stored in this table "xf_user_authenticate". If you are looking to change the password directly from database use this query.

```
 UPDATE xf_user_authenticate
SET data = BINARY
    CONCAT(
        CONCAT(
            CONCAT('a:3:{s:4:"hash";s:40:"', SHA1(CONCAT(SHA1('new-password').
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy hi,
Xenforo save his user password in "xf_user_authenticate" table, as BLOB formate